# Tips for learning a new framework/updating an existing enterprise application -.NET

Tags: .net, architecture

I come across several situations which involve customizing a MS framework (Ex: Built a layer above the webparts framework to utilize it in an application) or extending an existing app's functionality. I've realized that the key point is to get familiar with the class library so that I can start writing classes that inherit from existing classes or extend the functionality by using interfaces etc.

Currently, the first thing I do is:

- Create a class diagram to understand the high level structure
- Get hold of quickstart apps written for that framework and step through the code.

What tips do you follow to get familiar with the code and get comfortable in extending the functionality.

Comment: I usually go for practice.  It's not all trial and error, but it's the same thing when you move to a new area- the only way to become familiar is to drive around.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470183/what-did-you-do-to-learn-language-framework-xx. There are many, many other variations of the "how did you learn..." theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pick the simplest feature that you need to add, and work on that first

then the next feature, and so on

the learning curve for the first feature may be very steep, but it should level out as you begin to cover more of the framework

though there is merit in learning the entire framework before plunging in, there is also the possibility that you don't need to know 100% of the framework to get the job done, but only 10%

so learn that focused 10% first, and test your knowledge with a practical application (the features)

Comment: My thinking is that if we really have to write clean elegant code, we will need to write components that nicely plugs into the existing architecture and for us to do that, we need to know as much as possible about the framework (> 10%?)

Comment: @user102533: at the moment, that is an assumption. It could be 10%, it could be 99%. You won't know until you _try something_.